# Is this some kind of fake render?

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-effects

Why setting state to same value executes the body of the component?

here is the demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fake-render-lcrcpd

1. Why setting the state to the same value "t" causes "rerender"?
2. Why console.log in the body of the component logs 3, but the rendered value is 2?
3. Why the effect without dependency does not get triggered when the log in the body shows 3?
4. Does that mean it is not safe to update ref's value directly in the body of the component?

First time clicking the button displays render count 2 -> 4, it skips 3, because it is the previous known value, but not the one that is rendered

Comment: React is at leisure to call your component function as many times as it likes (and it will happily do so twice in strict mode). That's why they should be side effect free – and yours isn't, since it's mutating that boxed ref.

Comment: @AKX Why so? Is it mentioned somewhere in the documentation that it is free to call the component without updating the Virtual DOM and executing the side effects? I don't think there is something strange in my code that react does not accept. I should be able to mutate that ref freely.

Comment: Yes: https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#updates-to-strict-mode

Comment: @AKX but there is no strict mode in my example

Comment: You're using `createRoot`. Same effect.

Comment: @AKX but it works like this even on version 16.8, when hooks are introduced, when ```createRoot``` didn't even exist. Are you saying that react just works that way? It just randomly executes the body of the component whenever it decides? There are plenty of resources online that uses same approach like me to track render count, does that mean all of them are not valid? Where this behavior is mentioned?

Comment: Not randomly, but yes, React works that way. And yes, tracking how many times your function is called is likely pointless, and those resources are likely wrong.

Comment: @AKX what that execution is called, it is not rerendering. If not randomly, then when? In my example if the initial value of the state was the value that I am setting inside the effect ("t"), that behavior wouldn't happen. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have found:

Setting a state with the same value does not cause rerender. It is not a rerender. It just executes the body of the component without going deep to its children and without the hooks. It is mentioned in the documentation

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

> Bailing out of a state update If you update a State Hook to the same
> value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the
> children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison
> algorithm.)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree.

And  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14810