# React component re-renders twice on setState even though state stays the same

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand when exactly the React component re-renders when I call the setState function without actually changing the state. From what I understand about the reconciliation phase the framework should recognize that the state has not changed and the component should not be rendered again.

I am using the following code to test (**I disabled StrictMode** for tests):

```
function App() {
  const [isDisplayed, setIsDisplayed] = useState(false);
  console.log("hello");
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsDisplayed(true)}>Show</button>
      <button onClick={() => setIsDisplayed(false)}>Hide</button>
      {isDisplayed && <TestComponent />}
    </div>
  );
}

function TestComponent() {
  return <div>You can see me!</div>;
}
```

The initial state of `isDisplayed` is `false`, so when I click the 'Show' button the component is rendered again and "hello" appears in the console. When I click the 'Show' button again another "hello" appears in the console. If I continue clicking the Show button afterwards nothing is printed to the console.

The output of this code and my interaction is:

- 'hello'
- click(show)
- 'hello'
- click(show)
- 'hello'
- click(show)
- *nothing in console*

So my question is, why does it re-render exactly twice?

Comment: This is not exactly a rerender. It just executes the body of the component without children and hooks. Something like my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76579383/react-is-this-some-kind-of-fake-render . But I am still not sure why

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14810#issuecomment-462089702